# PHP: Find index of array in multidimentional array based on given value

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, arrays

I am trying to set up a form to allow users to update data in a large JSON file. I have a form that allows the user to grab the 'event' they want and to edit it. When they click submit, it sends the data to a script that pulls the entire JSON file into an array. From there, I need the script to search through that array and find the index of the sub-array that has the same ID as the 'event' that has been edited. So if the user has edited the entry called "William Bradford born", I need the script to match the ID "american-ccincore-1411541230" and return 0 for that sub-array's index.

```
[
  {
     "id" : "american",
     "title" : "A Timeline of American Literature",
     "description" : "LENGTHY DESCRIPTIVE TEXT",
     "initial_zoom" : "50",
     "focus_date" : "1650-01-01 00:00:00",
     "size_importance" : "true",
     "timezone" : "-06:00",
     "min_zoom" : "20",
     "max_zoom" : "80",
     "image_lane_height" : "50",
     "display_zoom_level" : "1",
     "tags" : {
       "Puritan" : "0",
       "Enlightenment" : "0",
       "Romantic" : "0",
       "Transcendental" : "0",
       "Dark Romantic":  "0",
       "African American": "0",
       "American Indian": "0",
       "International" : "0"
     },
     "legend": [
       {
         "title": "Author event",
         "icon": "star_red.png"
       },
       {
         "title": "Publication event",
         "icon": "square_blue.png"
       },
       {
         "title": "Historical event",
         "icon": "triangle_green.png"
       }
     ],
     "events": [
       {
         "id": "american-ccincore-1411541230",
         "title": "William Bradford born",
         "description": "LENGTHY DESCRIPTIVE TEXT",
         "tags": "Puritan",
         "startdate": "1950-03- 00:00:00",
         "enddate": "1657-05- 00:00:00",
         "importance": "50",
         "date_display": "year",
         "link": "",
         "image": "https://www.csustan.edu/sites/default/files/ENGLISH/reuben/pal/chap1/bradford.gif",
         "icon": "star_red.png",
         "span_color": "#f66"
       }, {
         "id": "american-mforkner-1411364607",
         "title": "Church Mission Society",
         "description": "LENGTHY DESCRIPTIVE TEXT",
         "tags": "",
         "startdate": "1799-01-01 00:00:00",
         "enddate": "1799-01-01 00:00:00",
         "importance": "50",
         "date_display": "year",
         "link": "",
         "image": "http://webarchive.cms-uk.org/_images/tnsaies1.jpg",
         "icon": ".png",
         "span_color": "#ccc"
       }
     ]
  }
]
```

I've tried to adapt scripts suggested in a dozen or so posts here, but I can't get any to work in this particular situation. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Change this to `var_export()` instead of `var_dump()` so people don't have to retype the data structure

Comment: where are the codes you're working on?

Comment: Now that the data is in a usable state, the next obvious question is "What data is being sent back and forth on an edit event?" For example, if you only get the modified value, how are you going to find what the original value was?

Comment: Can you put a before and after of the array? And the type of input that you will be accepting to change the array (basically what TML asked)? Need more information to work with. Also, when you are working with this, is it a PHP array, or a json object?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a simple loop.  The caveat is you need to distinguish between an answer of `0` and a failure to find the event you were looking for.  I typically use `false` to indicate failure, but that means using `===` or `!==` for your comparison later.

```
function findEventIndexById($events, $target) {
    $retval = false;
    foreach($events as $index=>$oneEvent) {
        if ($oneEvent->id == $target) {
            $retval = $index;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $retval;
}

$foundIndex = findEventIndexById($data->events, $eventId);
if ($foundIndex !== false) {
     // ... do stuff here to $data->events[$foundIndex]
} else
    // ... report an error ...
```

Comment: how can you add like $oneEvent->id ..$oneEvent is not an object of any class ??

Comment: I'm assuming the JSON data was decoded with `json_decode()`.  What you get is an object with an attribute called `events`, which is an array of objects.  Those objects have an `id` attribute.